# Magento 2 Customer address attribute values not save to database

Tags: magento2

I have created a customer address attribute in magento2 enterprise edition backend. The attribute is showing in frontend. But the attribute value is not save to database while register as a customer.

I have tested all the Magento2 EE. The issue is happen in all the version of MagentoEE2x